# Can't select a Snapshot when using the 'Create Similar' VM

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm used to creating new VM instances from the 'Create Similar' link from an existing VM.  Then I attached a Snapshot disk.

However, I've just tried to do my normal process and the 'Change' button doesn't work anymore under 'Boot Disk' option.  I used to be able to select this and then choose a Snapshot.  Clicking it does nothing now.

Is there a fault with this process or has the process changes?

Thanks
Adam

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OJUc.jpg)

Comment: Did you try on another computer / browser ?

Comment: Yes I've tried responsive and also Edge - the button is clickable but it doesn't open the usual modal to select a disk / snapshot.

Comment: Are you the owner of the project or just a user with some permissions ? You need [this set of permissions to create a VM from a snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance) - make sure your account has the role with these permissions.